# Jasmine custom matchers and before all

Tags: javascript, jasmine

When using Jasmine, is there a difference between adding a matcher in a `beforeAll` block vs a `beforeEach` block?

As far as I can tell, it works both ways. However, every documentation/tutorial I find online uses `beforeEach`. Is this simply because Jasmine's built-in `beforeAll` block is a relatively new feature, or is it avoided due to a potential pitfall when running the tests?

Using `beforeAll` makes more sense to me (why add the same matcher more than once?), but I'd like to make sure that I'm not exposing my tests to any problems.

Comment: Interesting question! This is related I think: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/721

Answer (score 2):

There are two differences - 1) the execution order, and 2) the scope in which the change is persistent. I've spent many hours testing in Jasmine at work and the differences between `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` have always behaved as they should (well, except one [bug](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/846) I helped them fix). The only reason I've found to use `beforeEach` instead of `beforeAll` is to avoid test pollution. This isn't an issue for custom matchers, so it should be just fine to go ahead and use `beforeAll`.

*Execution order* - in any given `describe` block, order is as follows:

- its `beforeAll`
- its `beforeEach`
- its first nested `it` or `describe` block (including their setups and teardowns)
- its `afterEach`
- for each additional nested `it` or `describe` block, repeat the last three steps
- its `afterAll`

I've confirmed this through testing and sources like [this](http://coderdiaries.com/2014/05/30/jasminejs-execution-sequence-whith-nested-describes/).

*Scope* - Any added variables, properties on the [this](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-The_<code>this</code>_keyword) keyword, [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Spies), or [custom matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_matcher.html) (as mentioned), will be persistent and accessible in the given block, throughout the block (including in nested blocks), as soon as the code that adds them has been executed. For example, if I set `this.foo` in the `beforeAll` of a `describe`, it can be accessed in that `describe`'s `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, `afterAll`, and `it` and `describe` blocks. As soon as I leave the describe block, `this.foo` will no longer be accessible.

Comment: I can understand how using spies and 'this' would cause test pollution, but how would adding a custom matcher be considered pollution?

Comment: You're right, adding a custom matcher shouldn't cause test pollution. (If it did, it would rely on state, which a matcher should not do.) I'll update my answer so it doesn't suggest that.

Comment: Exactly... Using `beforeEach` probably leads to redundant code execution. It's a shame Jasmine doesn't have built in configuration functionality... (as far as I'm aware, at least. I'm still new to it).

Comment: What do you mean by configuration functionality? Personally, I use the "helper" files for configuration. The code in the helper file is executed before any tests run. For example, I set properties on the `this` object in my helper files (in the `beforeAll` function so the properties will be in scope during my tests).

Comment: I'm using it outside of the browser, which makes it a tad difficult to maintain Jasmine from file to file.

Comment: Are you using node js? Because, the helper files also work with the npm Jasmine package.

Comment: Using it with NPM and Gulp

Comment: In that case, any `.js` files you have in the spec/helpers directory (unless you change this path in your Jasmine config) will be automatically loaded. For example, take a look at the end of https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303